# Show an image instead of app_name in android manifest

Tags: android, android-layout, android-manifest

```
I want to show an image in place of app_name.
android:label="@string/app_name".
```

Instead    of    the string/ app_name, i want an image to be displayed there. can anyone       suggest me how to do this. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

why you wanna show an image instead of the application name ? where you can you this to show your application icon

```
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
```

---

```
    android:label="@string/app_name"
```

is for the application name. ain't for an image.

Comment: I want to show an image in the title bar. image will be app_name but along wid some designing.. plz suggest something

Comment: did you mean to show the image at your application actionbar ? ? if so then use custom header or if you targeting >10 then use android actionbar